# Search Yammer for threads between date & time range?

Tags: web-services, api, rest, search, yammer

I'm trying to execute a REST query to Yammer that will retrieve all threads (message starters) between a specified date AND **time**.
I noticed the search/search_tabs.json accepts "search_startdate/search_enddate" filters (though not documented) but not sure if the date is date-only or date/time.
While the messages.json has a "newer/older_than", but they accept ID's not date/time.

So I guess my question is:

1. Would the messages.json or search.json be more appropriate for this task?
2. Is there any additional documentation on search, the developer site just has "**search** - The search query." - what do these "queries" look like?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0):

search_startdate and search_enddate only accept date inputs, not time or datetime inputs. I don't know if these are actually accessible through the API. To answer your questions:

1 - Neither will work for what you're trying to do

2 - I believe that the content of the search query is just the plaintext you want to look for, e.g., to search for "test" you would use https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json?search=test